# Android retrieving phone contacts query takes long time

Tags: java, android, sql

Hello i am using the next code for retrieving phone contacts name,number and its taked to long.
After littel search i found the the cursor.moveToFirst() command is that one who cuz this .
But i couldent find any solution ): may some one help me please ? 
Thanks !

```
public void loadPhoneMembers(){

    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver(); 
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{ id }, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                {
                       String contactNumber=pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                       String contactName =    
pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                       if(!phonesAdded.contains(contactNumber)){
                        members.add(contactName+","+contactNumber);  // members is arrayList
                        }

                    break;
                }
                pCur.close();
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;
    }

}
```

Comment: what are the fields that you exactly need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are querying one extra Cursor for each Contact from your first query. You can query the Names and TelephoneNumbers in one query and ignore the  Contacts without Telephone number.

```
String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI};
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,projection, null, null, null);
```

Also, `while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            }`

has same effect as the following.

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {

    } while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;
```

Comment: use full answer this will reduce the lot of time to load contacts